# Undefined variable: POST in C:\wamp\www\forms.php

Tags: php, html

The following code doesn't work.  `forms.php` and `forms.html` are the file names, both saved in the root directory.

The error is "`Undefined variable: POST in C:\wamp\www\forms.php`".  I know I'm not handling multiple inputs properly, either. Can anyone help with either of these?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Registration for Placement
</title> 
</head>


<body>
<h1> Start your Placement process...NOW...</h1>
<form action = "forms.php" method = "POST">
<p> Name <input name = "Name" type = "Text" size = "20" maxlength = "30">
<p> Branch: CSE<input name = "branch" type = "radio" >
            ECE<input name = "branch" type = "radio">
            MEC<input name = "branch" type = "radio">
<p> Languages Known:English<input name ="lang[]" type = "checkbox" value = "1">
                    Hindi<input name = "lang[]" type = "checkbox" value = "2">
                    Tamil<input name = "lang[]" type = "checkbox" value = "3">
<p> State<select name = "state" size = "2">
        <option> Jammu and Kashmir
        <option> Delhi
        <option> Tamil Nadu
        <option> M.P
        <option> U.P
        <option> Maharashtra
        </select>
<p> Thanks for submimitting the form
<p><input type = "Submit" value = "enter" >
    <input type = "Reset" value = "clear"  >


    </form>
</body>

</html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Thank You</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Thank You</h1>
<p>Thank you for registering. Here is the information you submitted:</p>

<p>Name </p><p><?php echo  $POST['Name']; ?></p>
<p>Branch </p><p><?php echo $POST["branch"];?></p>
<p>Lang </p><p><?php echo $POST["lang[0]"];?></p>
<p>STATE </p><p><?php echo $POST["state"];?></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A couple of things about your code: 1. Why do you have a space between your attribute names and their value (`type = "Submit"` instead of `type="Submit"`? There shouldn't be a need for a space. 2. It's best to use a DOCTYPE - at the top of the page write `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the very top line (before the `<html>` tag)

Comment: ok..i removed the spaces as well added the doctype..but in vain

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `$POST`, use `$_POST`, more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 3):

you should   write like this

$_POST['Name']   
 or 

$_REQUEST['Name']

Answer (score 2):

Its `$_POST` not `$POST` also you should be checking the variable is defined and set, also you should use `htmlspecialchars()` on user input when outputting to save you from a XSS vulnerability:

```
<?php 
echo isset($POST['Name']) ? '<p>'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['Name']).'</p>' : null; 
?>
```

Comment: i copied ur code "of the htmlentities" bt yet it doesnt show ny thing ..also i corrected to $_POST....does it hav ny oder prblm?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know much but maybe the "double quotes" are creating a problem. Try using

```
$_POST['state'];
```

This might do the trick.